# Adding new columns in Koalas DataFrame using assign

Tags: spark-koalas

I have a Koalas DataFrame and I want to add a new column by calculating using two columns. I have a separate function that do the calculation and return the value of the new column for each rows. The *calculate* function is a bit complex.

`df.assign(new_column=lambda x: self.calculate(x.col1, x.col2))`

My issue is *x.col1* and *x.col2* are not passed as individual row values, rather the entire columns as series is passed to the *calculate* function, which cause to throw a TypeError.

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Series'`

Anyone has any idea how I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `self.calculate` function to be compatible with a `Series`.

In your case, instead of using `float()` on a value, use `.astype(float)` on the `Series`